# Swift deleting file from folder in documents directory

Tags: swift, url

I appreciate some assistance. I created a folder inside my documents directory named "MyPhotos". I added three image files to the folder. No issues.
Next I'm attempting to construct some code that will delete the files when needed but can't get it right. I can append the MyPhotos folder to the search path but can't subsequently append the file name to the path after multiple tries. tempPhotoTitle is a variable. Thank you for helping.

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

       let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask,true)[0] as NSString

        let destinationPath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("MyPhotos")

        let finalPath = destinationPath.appending(tempPhotoTitle)

        do {
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: finalPath)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue there is that you are working with strings (paths) and not adding the slash. I recommend always working with URLs this way you dont need to worry about adding the slash to your path.

```
do {
    let tempPhotoTitle = "filename.jpg"
    let documents = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let photos = documents.appendingPathComponent("MyPhotos")
    let fileURL = photos.appendingPathComponent(tempPhotoTitle)
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Leo Dabus's answer of working with URLs is the better one. However, it's worth mentioning that when working with `String`s, if you bridge to `NSString` again, `appendingPathComponent` is available:

```
let finalPath = (destinationPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent(tempPhotoTitle)
```